# What is the significance of the different languages in the collation field when building a mysql database

Tags: mysql, collation

I'm relatively familiar with the significance of utf-8, ci, unicode, etc. But what is the primary difference between the multiple language options (latin1_swedish, latin2_general, latin1_german, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This affects how the strings are sorted and compared.

From the docs:

> `latin1_german1_ci` (dictionary) rules:
>
> ```
> Ä = A
> Ö = O
> Ü = U
> ß = s
> ```
>
> `latin1_german2_ci` (phone-book) rules:
>
> ```
> Ä = AE
> Ö = OE
> Ü = UE
> ß = ss
> ```

This means that if you define a column with `latin2_german2_ci` and issue a query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   mycolumn = 'Mueller'
```

it will return `Müller`, which it wouldn't if the column would have been defined `latin1_german1_ci`